# NSURL URLWithString:myString returns Nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurl

I have a string of my url.. I want to get data from that url. For that I needs to create object of `NSURL`. The problem is while I try `URLWithString` method of NSURL class it returns nil. But when I opens this link in Safari of My Mac it display me the Image.

I am using ..

```
NSString *str = @"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chld=L|0&chl=http://MyServer.com/shareMyCard.php?value=1304057103";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

I don't know why the URL is Nil. I think because of query string in my string.

Any Idea how to get data from this Url String.

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your URL is nil because it contains special chars, use this following function to encode your url  parameters before using them in URL -

```
-(NSString *) URLEncodeString:(NSString *) str
{

    NSMutableString *tempStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:str];
    [tempStr replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [tempStr length])];


    return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tempStr] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: I know it's late in the day but thank you very much for this - solved my problem too.