# Loading a UIWebview when pressing a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am developing a simple testing app for iPhone. I want to click a button to change the `URL` of `webview`, then load the new URL. Here is my code:

```
NSString *nurl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.abc.com/abc.aspx?SN=%@&fdate=%@&tdate=%@", SNstr, fDate, tDate];

NSLog(@"################: %@", nurl);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:nurl];

NSLog(@"################: %@", url);

NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];



[Logs loadRequest:req];
```

It is working well inside `viewDidLoad`. 
I move it into a button:

```
-(IBAction)CheckLog:(id)sender
{
    // codes here
}
```

When I press the button, it gives `nurl`'s value correct, but `url`'s value is null. So nothing is changed on the UIWebView `Logs`.

Why could this be, when the code runs correctly in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: The single thing that is not related to the question is which IDE you use (Xcode in this case). Is this for iOS by any chance? If so, you should tag it as such instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your button action will be like this...

```
-(IBAction)CheckLog:(id)sender
{
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

 NSString *nurl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.abc.com/abc.aspx?SN=%@&fdate=%@&tdate=%@", SNstr, fDate, tDate];

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [nurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ];

   // NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.co.in/"]; // Your new URL 

    [self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

Comment: And make sure you connected `self.myWebView` in IBOutlet.

Comment: I have done so as your way. now I find strainge problem: if there is no parameters in URL(like yours), it works. if I add parameters like mine, it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1359230 print the variables inside the method to check the value[SNstr, fDate, tDate]
NSLog(@"%@ : %@ : %@", SNstr, fDate, tDate);

Comment: I said "nurl's value correct, but url's value is null". It confused me very much...why does it become null after NSURL? have you tried?

Comment: where you declared these values [SNstr, fDate, tDate] , i meant the scope

Comment: It is a tab bar controller app. I declare them in AppDelegate.m, and "extern" them in the firstViewController.m. from URL's value, these 3 variables get the correct values. but at line of NSURL, they are gone.

Comment: pls refer this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839877/nsurl-urlwithstringmystring-returns-nil

Comment: @STANLEY [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Try this...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is that the method is definitely being called. Are your `NSLog` statements being printed? If not, check that you have connected the button to the IBAction correctly in Interface Builder.

I can't see anything in your code that is immediately jumping out to me as incorrect, so your best bet is to set a breakpoint at the start of the method and step through it line-by-line, checking the values of each variable as you go.

Comment: Did you read the question? It states "When I press the button, it gives nurl's value correct". This indicates that the button itself works correctly, so your first statement is redundant. For your second statement, it isn't really an answer it is more of a comment.