# UIImage in UICollectionView not showing

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

For some reason, I can not get my base 64 encoded image to show in a `UIImageView` in a `UICollectionView`.

Here is my code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"task_cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary* json = [dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    UILabel *text = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];

    NSString *ext = [[json objectForKey:@"image"] pathExtension];
    NSString *final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/%@;base64,%@", ext, [json objectForKey:@"b64img"]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:final];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];

    text.text = [json objectForKey:@"title"];

    return cell;
}
```

**DEBUG LOG:**

```
Printing description of final:
data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/......(goes on for a while)

url = nil

imageData is nil
```

I do see the `UILabel` changing.

So, what should I try.

Comment: I assume you checked that imageData is not nil?

Comment: Yeah, and it is for some reason. Why?

Comment: Are you sure `dataWithContentsOfURL` supports this?

Comment: @MarcusAdams yeah because I used how to from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366837/how-to-display-a-base64-image-within-a-uiimageview

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with how you construct the path to your image. This looks funky:

```
NSString *final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/%@;base64,%@", ext, [json objectForKey:@"b64img"]];
```

Please post the NSLog value of  `final`, `url` and whether or not `imageData` is nil at time of setting image.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following to fix it..

1. Change the code for the url:

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString URLEncodeString:final]];
2. Add the function URLEncodeString to NSString. I used the code from [NSURL URLWithString:myString returns Nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839877/nsurl-urlwithstringmystring-returns-nil). It works like a charm.

And presto...it works.